# Why are the answers different?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I have a double integral $$I=\int_{-100}^{100}\int_{-100}^{100}\left(\frac{1}{((z_1-z_2)^2)^{1/6}}-\frac{1}{(R^2+(z_1-z_2)^2)^{1/6}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z_1\,\mathrm{d}z_2~,$$
and the same integral can be written by change of variables $z=z_1-z_2$ and $z_+=(z_1+z_2)/2$ as
$$I=2\int_{-100}^{100}(100-|z|)\left(\frac{1}{(z^2)^{1/6}}-\frac{1}{(R^2+z^2)^{1/6}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z~.$$
If I use `NIntegrate`, then the results of the two expressions are very different at small $R$ (like $R=10^{-3}$), while at large $R$ (like $R=10$), they both yied similar results. Here are the codes

```
 I1[R_?NumericQ]:=  NIntegrate[(1/((z1-z2)^2)^(1/6) - 
       1/(R^2+(z1-z2)^2)^(1/6), {z1, -100, 100}, {z2, -100, 100}]
```

and

```
I2[R_?NumericQ]:=  2*NIntegrate[(100-Abs[z])(1/(z^2)^(1/6) - 
           1/(R^2+z^2)^(1/6), {z, -100, 100}]
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to make `NIntegrate` consistent even at small $R$, with speed not being too slow.

Comment: Please post the _Mathematica_ expressions you used so we can copy-paste them.

Comment: Alright, I have done that.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in the Mathematica code, and make `r` a variable so that people can test both the `r = 10^-3` and `r = 10` cases.

Comment: In any case, Mathematica might be having trouble with the singularity at $z_1=z_2$. Have you tried adding `Exclusions -> (z1 == z2)`?

Comment: Ok, fixed all syntax error.  @Rahul I tried that, and even with exclusion included, the result is about half of what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Mathematica can evaluate both integrals symbolically, although results provided are complicated -- include `Assumptions` and `ConditionalExpression`. Then it is possible to substitute in any numerical value of `R`. E.g., for `R = 0.001` results are: `2.5871` and `2.58936`, IMO they are very close. For bigger `R` results are not so similar: `R=10` gives `1157.95` and `1121.74`.

Comment: Try cutting, pasting, and executing your code in *Mathematica*. The errors do not seem fixed.

Comment: @Rahul's suggestion works for me.

Comment: Right, Michael, I added missing parenthesis myself to play with OP's code.

Comment: @Alx `2.5871` and `2.58936` sound quite different if from a symbolic, *exact* result. Try `N[<symbolic result here>, 10]`.  If they're different, perhaps there's something wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: @Alx Yes, but the OP should fix the post. It's only polite to have working code.

Comment: The other problem is that the second integral is incorrect. For one thing, if $z=z_1-z_2$ then its range should be $-200$ to $200$. There is another necessary change that I will post if the OP has the courtesy to actually fix all the syntax errors.

Comment: Added `Assumptions->R \[Element] Reals` to symbolic integrals, now results are more simple. With these changes at `R=0.001` one has `2.5871` and `2.58709`. But for `R = 10` difference is much bigger. I suppose the second integral of OP is wrong.

Comment: Although OP is missing, one can make symbolic computation of first integral to get `6/5 (6000 5^(1/3) + (40000 + R^2)^(5/6)) + (-((6 R^2)/5) - 80000 Hypergeometric2F1[1/6, 1/2, 3/2, -(40000/R^2)])/Abs[R]^(1/3)` and fill in any real value of `R`.